# Which of the followings is/are correct

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $p_n(x)=a_nx^2+b_nx+c_n$ be a sequence of quadratic polynomials where $a_n,b_n,c_n \in \mathbb R$, for all $n\geqq$ 1. Let $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ be distinct real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(\lambda_0)=A_0$,  $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(\lambda_1)=A_1$,   $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(\lambda_2)=A_2$. Then

> 1. $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n (x)$ exists for all $x\in \mathbb R$,
> 2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} p'_n(x)$ exists for all $x\in \mathbb R$,
> 3. $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(\frac{\lambda_0+\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{3})$ does not exist,
> 4. $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n'(\frac{\lambda_0+\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{3})$ does not exist.

Comment: What is you personal work on the subject ?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't get any idea to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. By solving the linear system
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
\lambda_0^2 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
\lambda_1^2 & \lambda_1\ & 1 \\
\lambda_2^2 & \lambda_2 & 1 \\
\end{array}} \right)
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
a_n \\
b_n \\
c_n \\
\end{array}} \right)=
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
p_n(\lambda_0) \\
p_n(\lambda_1) \\
p_n(\lambda_2) \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
it follows that sequences $(a_n)_n$,  $(b_n)_n$,  $(c_n)_n$ have limits. Note that the determinant of the [(Vandermonde) matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is $(\lambda_0-\lambda_1)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\lambda_0-\lambda_2)\not=0$